# Javascript not triggering on FB page, works on host server

Tags: javascript, facebook, dom-events

Newcomer to Facebook App/Page programming so please, be gentle. :) I've searched long and hard for the answer to this but simply cannot find anything.

I created an App to add a tab to a FB page. The tab shows up on the page. The page loads in the iframe. Basically everything works except the Javascript. I have a "Select" box which calls on Javacript to change the source of the iFrame within the page itself. (Inside the FB iframe). The script works on the hosting server ([here](http://www.affiche-toi.ca/clients/pneuschartrand/fb/)).

What am I missing?

**JS code:**

```
function JumpToIt(list) {
    var newPage = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value
    if (newPage != "None") {
        parent.succursale.location.href=newPage
    }
}
```

Comment: Same-origin policy? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/28/explaining-same-origin-policy-part-1-deny-read.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your page is embedded in your facebook page, `parent.succorsale...` refers to the parent window, i.e. the Facebook page. [Same origin policy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/28/explaining-same-origin-policy-part-1-deny-read.aspx) prevents code on your site from messing with that.

Instead, try:

```
window.succorsale.location.href = newPage;
```

(I haven't tested this, so I'm hoping it works... :)

Comment: Seems I came to the right place. Worked like a charm! Thanks so much.